# Client error response 499 Client Disconnect on moving files in Rackspace Container

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I am executing a script for copying selected media files from one container to another container in rackspace. This was always working but from last day it is continuously giving error:

> Exception in uploading Observation Media.Client error response [status code] 499 [reason phrase] Client Disconnect [url] https://snet-storage101.lon3.clouddrive.com/v1/MossoCloudFS_f448a09c-45b1-4ec3-bcb5-15d9e77c3bea/container-name/media.mp4

I thought its client side so I have set `ignore_user_abort(true)` and `set_time_limit(0)`. But still it is not working.

If I skip that media using query than it stucks in other media files. Although I can check each media file is playing in web. So this seems to be some rackspace issue.
Please help